# How to save and resume tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am new in this field and hope you can help me :)
I am training my TensorFlow model in Google Colab, but because of time is limited there I can't run more than 2 epochs, since my data is huge.

```
history = model.fit(
  x=data.train_x, 
  y=data.train_y,
  validation_split=0.2,
  batch_size=32,
  shuffle=True,
  epochs=2,
  callbacks=[tensorboard_callback]

Epoch 1/2
22016/22016 [==============================] - 14481s 657ms/step - loss: 0.3934 - acc: 0.8225 - val_loss: 0.3893 - val_acc: 0.8289
Epoch 2/2
22016/22016 [==============================] - 14466s 657ms/step - loss: 0.2807 - acc: 0.8825 - val_loss: 0.3793 - val_acc: 0.8348
```

My question is if it is possible to save this model and resume training the next day from 3rd epoch?

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem. If not, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You will lose the `history` object which you can plot loss and metrics. When you save the model history object is **not** preserved.

You need to set `initial_epoch` parameter. Example:

```
model.fit(
    ds_train,
    epochs=2,
    validation_data=ds_test,
)

Epoch 1/2
469/469 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.3593 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9015 - val_loss: 0.1918 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9438
Epoch 2/2
469/469 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1628 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9537 - val_loss: 0.1329 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9621
```

Suppose you saved it with:

```
model.save('model.h5')
```

Load it back with:

```
restored_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/model.h5') # path here
```

Now you can fit again:

```
restored_model.fit(
    ds_train,
    initial_epoch=2,
    validation_data=ds_test,
    epochs = 5
)

Epoch 3/5
469/469 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1169 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9663 - val_loss: 0.1097 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9671
Epoch 4/5
469/469 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0901 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9735 - val_loss: 0.0942 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9719
Epoch 5/5
469/469 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0730 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9789 - val_loss: 0.0865 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9724
```